# Jinja2 truncate string variable not working

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

My Python application is using Jinja for the front end.  I am trying to truncate the variable that is a string, however it is not working.

I can truncate a string but not a variable.

This fails to truncate:

```
{{ pagetitle | truncate(9,True,'') }}
```

This truncates to `foo bar b`:

```
{{ "foo bar baz qux"|truncate(9,True,'') }}
```

I think I have figured this out.
It appears to only trim phrases? `{{ "foo bar baz qux"|truncate(9,True,'') }}` will truncate, however `{{ "foobarbazqux"|truncate(9,True,'') }}` will not truncate.

Comment: "This fails to truncate." - What **exactly** happens in that case? Does it shows an error? Or prints something?

Comment: No it doesn't fail or anything.  prints the full string `foo bar baz qux` and truncate is ignored.

Comment: So, the difference is not about a string variable and a string literal, it is about the **content** of the string, am I correctly understand your last edit? Please, update the question title and beginning of the post to reflect **actual** state of affairs. In the current form the question is quite misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fourth parameter to truncate, and this is the one allowing you to achieve what you are looking for.

> Strings that only exceed the length by the tolerance margin given in the fourth parameter will not be truncated.

So, given:

```
{{ 'foobarbazqux' | truncate(9, True, '', 0) }}
```

This yields:

```
foobarbaz
```

So, in your case:

```
{{ pagetitle | truncate(9, True, '', 0) }}
```

---

This said, since you are using `truncate` without an ellipsis and want to cut in word (the second parameter is `True`), you could also consider going for a simpler [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/2123530):

```
{{ 'foobarbazqux'[0:9] }}
```

So, in your case:

```
{{ pagetitle[0:9] }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to add an optional leeway value.  Not sure what the leeway value is doing.  But it's truncating correctly.

```
pagetitle='whateverwhatever'
{{ pagetitle | truncate(9,True,'',0) }}
```